# SQL - Case statement for exception

Tags: oracle, exception, case

I have a database represented (very simplified) as the following.

```
NAME                    BOSS                            TYPE

TestPerson1             TestBoss1                       1
TestPerson1             TestBoss2                       1
TestPerson1             TestBoss3                       1
TestPerson1             TestBoss1                       2
```

How do I get the name and boss when type is 2 (even if exists type 1)

I know I should use case and exists clauses, but I'm lost how to do that.

For that values, I'd like the query to return

```
TestPerson1             TestBoss2                       1
TestPerson1             TestBoss3                       1
TestPerson1             TestBoss1                       2
```

Comment: looks like select name, boss, max(type) from tab group by name, boss;

Comment: I'm wondering if it's been oversimplified... do you really have all the records for the same `name`, and the same `boss` repeated with a different type? And what does the title have to do with the question? Why do you think you should use case and exists?

Comment: Yes, the numbers are correct, they represent the same person and boss. If there is (person1, boss1, 2) there will be for SURE (person1, boss1, 1). But I need to return only the register with type 2. Because 2 has priority over 1. The title is because I don't know how to explain my problem in a few words...